# DeploymentItem doesn't work with TestInitialze()

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, deployment, tfs

I need to copy some directories/files for MS Unit test, and I have this code.

```
[TestInitialize()]
[DeploymentItem("\\library", "library")]
public void Initialize()
{
    ....
}
```

The problem is that the directory/files are not copied with `[TestInitialize()]`, I needed to use as follows:

```
[TestMethod]
[DeploymentItem("\\library", "library")]
public void AddInt16()
{
    ...
}
```

Am I supposed to use DeploymentItem only with `[TestMethod]`? If not, what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use it at a method *or* class level:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public sealed class DeploymentItemAttribute : Attribute
```

so, a good workaround given that its not picked up by `TestInitialize` is to move the `DeploymentItem` to your class.

Answer (score 1):

Either define the deployment item at class level or at the *.testrunconfig* file.